# how to use .click() command in a try-catch block java android

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

i am trying to click a element in a **android** app after catching a nosuchelementexception with try-catch method using this code here

```
    try {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageButton[@index='0']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2500);
    }

    catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e1) {
        Thread.sleep(45000);

        driver.findElement(By.id(com.offerup:id/dialog_pos_button)).click();


    }

}
```

but at `driver.findElement(By.id(com.offerup:id/dialog_pos_button)).click();`

it says that `com.offerup` cannont be resolved to a type, and `dialog_pos_button` cannot be resolved to a variable

does anyone know how to get around this?

here are my desired capabilities

```
File OfferUp = new File("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\com.offerup.apk");
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Virtual Device");
cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
cap.setCapability("null", "OfferUp");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.offerup");
cap.setCapability("appActivity",
"com.offerup.android.activities.SearchActivity");
```

Comment: can you add the error log from appium server?

Answer (score 1):

There is no any 'null' capability in Appium. You need to provide provide app capability if the app is not installed in your device.

[image]

Change **cap.setCapability("null", "OfferUp");** to

```
cap.setCapability("app", /path/to/.apk/file);
```

> If you provide app in DesiredCapability, you don't need to provide appPackage and appActivity capability.
>
> Using **Thread.sleep()** is not recommended. Use **ExplicitWait()** method.

Why do you want to click button in catch method? What if error is thrown from catch block? You must change your logic for that. First check if the element is Visible using **.isDisplayed()** method. Then if element is present click the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:-

> File filePath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")); File appDir
>   = new File(filePath, "/app"); File app = new File(appDir, "com.offerup.apk"); DesiredCapabilities cap = new
>   DesiredCapabilities(); cap.setCapability("app",
>   app.getAbsolutePath());    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Virtual
>   Device"); cap.setCapability("platformName", "android"); driver = new
>   AndroidDriver (new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

or try use different locator to identify particular element